# How auto load items on page

Tags: theming

Taxonomy page will have sidebar which will have taxonomy menu items and grid layout with image and brief details.

For example, taxonomy items have brand by certain names, price range, etc. User click on brand name, the grid layout will auto load the brand products without have going to /products/brand_name. On page, it will be /products, and then every brand name will show different products automatically loading on same page.

Is there such a way to do this? Or there is a module which can do that?

Example I found is 
http://www.cynosure.com/products/

Click on any from menu on left column, you will see the products reloaded by menu click.

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved using exposed filters feature of the [Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views) module. Here is an article explaining this process in detail.

http://www.bryanbraun.com/2013/08/06/drupal-tutorials-exposed-filters-with-views

You would also need the [Better Exposed Filters](https://www.drupal.org/project/better_exposed_filters)(BEF) module for displaying the filters as links.

Comment: thanks. so it will work with menu together? or I can use taxonomy menu block in the left column while in right column use view?

Comment: The left part is the exposed filter of the view and right part displays the results. There is no menu or menu block required. Add your taxonomy term fields as filters and expose them to the users. Using BEF module display the filters as menu/links instead of a select box.

Comment: tried BEF but couldnt find "menu/link on BEF" - where do you see that?

Answer (score 0):

[Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views) module will do this for you. If the items in the column is limited and you know what they are, you can create different pages for every one, each page indicates certain filtering. but you need Ajax call to load information in the same page. if your View name is product and then you need some thing like this

```
        $.ajax({
            url: Drupal.settings.basePath + 'views/ajax',
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: 'view_name=product&view_display_id='+view_display_id,
            success: function(response) {
              var output = response[1].data;
              $("#A_CONTAINER_TO_DISPLAY_CONTENT").html(output);
            },
            error: function(data) {
                $("#A_CONTAINER_TO_DISPLAY_CONTENT").css("display","none");
                alert('An error occured!');
            }
          });
```

`view_display_id` is the machine name in here:

[image]

And don't forget to set the use Ajax to `yes`

Comment: thanks, but where I put the example code in?

Comment: This Ajax function should be in the `click` event of the links in the left column. This is javascript code code, so foreach link you need to set `view_display_id` value

Comment: sorry where is click in left column? Is it in view?

Comment: No, There is a list of titles in the left column of products, right? When each one is clicked its relevant content should be loaded via Ajax. So for every link in the list you should raise an `on click` event.

Comment: Oh. I dont quite get it but I will try checking and see if i can get it

Comment: It is about javascript and you need to raise onclick event for titles in the left column

Comment: one more question - if i have taxonomy menu block on left, i can use javascript to raise onclick event for title on menu block then it will work?

Comment: sorry again, "you can create different pages for every one, each page indicates certain filtering." -- it means I have to create different page views for each filter, i.e. brands, pricing, etc? Also, I wonder if it is possible to list out the links instead of dropdown?

Comment: You can call any view in javascript events. If the list in the left column is based  on different pages of the view then you need to call different pages. If the view is based on contextual filter, then you need to call view and pass the filter variable to it. My code was just an Ajax call, it is up to you what view to call. Just implement any appropriate view to filter the result for each title in the left column, then call that view with the relevant variables and get the result.